# How to override hover and focus in child li element?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using WordPress

I have put an extra container in the navigation menu. The navigation menu has the id #access, and the extra container has the id #language-selection . The #language-selection container uses `<li>` elements, but the hover and focus are overridden by the following:

```
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #efefef;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#e5e5e5)); /* Older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    color: #373737;
}
```

How can i overwrite these rules, so that nothing happens on hover and on focus on the #language-selection container, when it is inside the #access container?

Following is the HTML:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
  <h3 class="assistive-text">Main menu</h3>
  <div class="skip-link">
    <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to primary content">Skip to primary content</a>
  </div>
  <div class="skip-link">
    <a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="Skip to secondary content">Skip to secondary content</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="page_item page-item-24 current_page_item">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?lang=en">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-26">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?page_id=26&amp;lang=en">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="language-selection">
    <ul class="qtrans_language_chooser" id="qtranslate-chooser">
      <li class="lang-en active">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?lang=en" hreflang="en" title="English" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_en">
          <span style="display:none">English</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lang-DK">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?lang=DK" hreflang="DK" title="Dansk" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_DK">
          <span style="display:none">Dansk</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lang-fa">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?lang=fa" hreflang="fa" title="Farsi" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_fa">
          <span style="display:none">Farsi</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="lang-ar">
        <a href="http://localhost/katarina/?lang=ar" hreflang="ar" title="???????" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_ar">
          <span style="display:none">???????</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="qtrans_widget_end"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So basically i want hover and focus to remain the same on the "Home" and "Contact" links, but to be deactivated on every li element inside #language-selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've provided the HTML, it's a little easier to see what you mean. My advice would be to add `.menu` as a specifier in the style so it only works within that container and doesn't include `#language-selection`. So:

```
#access a:focus { ... }
```

Then becomes

```
#access .menu a:focus { ... }
```

Then it will only apply that style to the anchors found within the `div.menu`.

The key is to be as specific with your style as possible. Just be careful though, because the more you apply the higher the styles [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) goes up. Meaning:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
    <a class="baz">Hello, world!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then apply:

```
#foo #bar a { color: red; } /* higher specificity */
#bar a.baz { color: green; }
```

The link will actually be red and not green.

Comment: I would still like the CSS to work on the "Home" and "Contact" links - see my edited question. I tried the first solution, it did not change :/

Comment: So how about `#access .menu a:active` (add `.menu` as an additional specifier so it doesn't include the other anchors)